# I cannot set default java with update-alternatives

Tags: java, openjdk, update-alternatives

I have installed three Versions of Java. I tried to set a default option with `update-alternatives`. However, it didn't change the default. What am I missing? I know that one is from JRE and the other two are from JDK, but all of them should work, I think. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ echo 1 | sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
------------------------------------------------------------
  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin/java              200       manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_251/bin/java            100       manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
```

I checked if jre1.8 version was ok:

```
$ ./jre1.8.0_251/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

However, default still is 14 from sdk.

```
$ java -version
java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: What do you get when you run "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version" ? I think because of the precedence of the java14 path in the $PATH env variable , what is actually being run is "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin/java" not "/usr/bin/java" . So alternatives don't work because of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think because of the precedence of the `java14` path in the `$PATH` environment variable , what is actually being run is `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1/bin/java` not `/usr/bin/java` . So alternatives won't work because of that.

Note that `/usr/bin/java` is just a symlink (i.e shortcut) to the default java binary.

A workaround is to use the [bash aliasing](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/) feature to map `java` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` :

```
alias java="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"
```

You can add it to your `~/.bashrc` file.